# How can I change the default register mutation in django-graphql-auth?

Tags: django, graphql

I want to change the fields of register mutation for example I want to ask for the password only once , and also I want do add extra fields like first_name , last_name, date_of_birth ... all of that , but still I want to beneficiate the use of the email verification and all the good parts that djang-graphql-auth brings .

So here is what I have right now  :

- A custom user (I only want the user to login using the email) :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
    
    
    class ExtendUser(AbstractUser):
    
        email = models.EmailField(blank=False, max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name="email")
        date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=False, null=True, verbose_name="date_of_birth")
        # phone = 
        # country = 
        city = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150, verbose_name="city")
        company_name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=150, 
        verbose_name="company_name")
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    
        # USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
        EMAIL_FIELD = "email
```

- In my schema.py I have the following :

> ```
> import graphene
> from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
> from .models import ExtendUser
> from graphql_auth import mutations
> from graphql_auth.schema import UserQuery, MeQuery
>
>
> class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
>     class Meta:
>         model = ExtendUser
>         fields = ("id", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "date_of_birth", "company_name", "city")
>
>
> class CreateUser(graphene.Mutation):
>     user = graphene.Field(UserType)
>
>     class Arguments:
>         first_name = graphene.String(required=True)
>         last_name = graphene.String(required=True)
>         # username = graphene.String(required=True)
>         email = graphene.String(required=True)
>         password = graphene.String(required=True)
>         date_of_birth = graphene.Date(required=True)
>         city = graphene.String(required=True)
>         company_name = graphene.String(required=True)
>
>
>
>     def mutate(self, info, first_name, last_name,  password, email, date_of_birth, city, company_name):
>         user = ExtendUser ( 
>             email = email,
>             first_name = first_name,
>             last_name = last_name,
>             date_of_birth = date_of_birth,
>             city = city,
>             company_name= company_name,
>         )
>         user.set_password(password)
>         user.save()
>
>         return CreateUser(user=user)
>
>
> class AuthMutation(graphene.ObjectType):
>     # register = mutations.Register.Field()
>     register = CreateUser.Field()
>     verify_account = mutations.VerifyAccount.Field()
>     token_auth = mutations.ObtainJSONWebToken.Field()
>     update_account = mutations.UpdateAccount.Field()
>     resend_activation_email = mutations.ResendActivationEmail.Field()
>     send_password_reset_email = mutations.SendPasswordResetEmail.Field()
>     password_reset = mutations.PasswordReset.Field()
>
>
>
> class RegisterUserQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
>     user_details = graphene.Field(UserType)
>     users = graphene.List(UserType)
>
>
>     def resolve_users(root, info):
>         user = info.context.user
>         if not user.is_authenticated:
>             raise Exception("Authentication credentials were not provided")
>         return ExtendUser.objects.all()
>
>
>     def resolve_user_details(root, info , **kwargs):
>         user = info.context.user
>         if not user.is_authenticated:
>             raise Exception('Not logged in!')
>         return ExtendUser.objects.get(email=user)
>
>
>
> class Query(RegisterUserQuery,UserQuery, MeQuery, graphene.ObjectType):
>     pass
>
>
> class Mutation(AuthMutation, graphene.ObjectType):
>     pass
>
>
> schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
> ```

But the way I've tried in the code above , is not sending the email verification anymore, how can I solve this , having all the verifications and everything graphql-auth brings , but to have a custom register mutation ?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this way:
In your User models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractUser, BaseUserManager, )
from django.db import models


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("The given email must be set")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", False)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)
        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_staff=True.")
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_superuser=True.")
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True, null=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True, null=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' #This is the modern way, where email is the username
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()
```

In your settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "account.User" #My User models is in the account app: account.models.User
GRAPHQL_AUTH = {
    'USERNAME_FIELD': ['email'], # Same as USERNAME_FIELD in User model
    'LOGIN_ALLOWED_FIELDS': ['email'],
    'USER_NODE_FILTER_FIELDS': {
        "email": ["exact", ],

        "is_active": ["exact"],
        "status__archived": ["exact"],
        "status__verified": ["exact"],
        "status__secondary_email": ["exact"],
    },
    'REGISTER_MUTATION_FIELDS': ['email', 'first_name'], #extend with your fields: city, date_of_birth, company
    'REGISTER_MUTATION_FIELDS_OPTIONAL': ['email'],
    'EMAIL_TEMPLATE_PASSWORD_RESET': "email/account_password_reset_email.html", # My modified template route
    'EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ACTIVATION': "email/account_activation_email.html", # My modified template route
    'EMAIL_SUBJECT_ACTIVATION': "email/account_activation_subject.txt", # My modified subject route
    'EMAIL_SUBJECT_PASSWORD_RESET': "email/account_password_reset_subject.txt", # My modified subject route
    "SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL": SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL, #A boolean parameter if you want activation or not
    "ACTIVATION_PATH_ON_EMAIL": config('ACTIVATION_PATH_ON_EMAIL', default="account/activate"), 
    "PASSWORD_RESET_PATH_ON_EMAIL": config('PASSWORD_RESET_PATH_ON_EMAIL', default="account/password-reset"),
    "ALLOW_LOGIN_NOT_VERIFIED": config('ALLOW_LOGIN_NOT_VERIFIED', default=False),
    "EXPIRATION_PASSWORD_RESET_TOKEN": config('EXPIRATION_PASSWORD_RESET_TOKEN', default=timedelta(hours=1)),
}
```